# How to show custom dialog dynamically in variant place in the device in android

Tags: android

I'm doing a tablet application. I have to show a custom dialog with the theme `android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar`.

Now I am able to show the dialog with the views as I required (i.e. with number picker at fixed position — on the left side of the screen).

I have to place the same dialog dynamically on the click position of a button. Some time on the left side of the screen and some time right.

Shortly we can say: at any position of the screen.

So please help me with any code or idea.

Comment: Do you use DialogFragment? Have you tried PopupWindow.showAtLocation()?